# How to transform dataframes to rdds in structured streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I get data from kafka using pyspark streaming, and the result is a dataframe, when I transform dataframe to rdd, it went wrong:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/docs/dp_model/dp_algo_platform/dp_algo_core/test/test.py", line 36, in <module>
df = df.rdd.map(lambda x: x.value.split(" ")).toDF()
File "/home/softs/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 91, in rdd
File "/home/softs/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
File "/home/softs/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;\nkafka'
```

the right version code:

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", "test") \
    .load()

df = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
df = df.withColumn("s", F.split(df['value'], " "))
df = df.withColumn('e', F.explode(df['s']))
# df = df.rdd.map(lambda x: x.value.split(" ")).toDF()

q = df.writeStream \
    .format("console") \
    .trigger(processingTime='30 seconds') \
    .start()

q.awaitTermination()
```

this is the wrong version code:

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", "test") \
    .load()

df = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
# df = df.withColumn("s", F.split(df['value'], " "))
# df = df.withColumn('e', F.explode(df['s']))
df = df.rdd.map(lambda x: x.value.split(" ")).toDF()

q = df.writeStream \
    .format("console") \
    .trigger(processingTime='30 seconds') \
    .start()

q.awaitTermination()
```

Why it cannot convert dataframe to rdd? and how can I do when I want to transform dataframe to rdd in pyspark streaming?

Answer (score 3):

If your spark version is 2.4.0 and above then u can use below alternative to play around with each row of your dataframe.

```
query=df.writeStream.foreach(Customized method to work on each row of dataframe rather than RDD).outputMode("update").start()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Eg:foreach class below will parse each row from the structured streaming dataframe and pass it to class SendToKudu_ForeachWriter, which will have the logic to convert it into rdd. The row passed will be in form of dataframe hence it can be converted into rdd using df.rdd.
class SendToKudu_ForeachWriter(): 
        def process(self, row):
                 #Your logic to work on row passed as dataframe here"
 if __name__ == '__main__': 
 query=streaming_parsed_dataframe.writeStream.foreach(SendToKudu_ForeachWriter()).outputMode("update").start()
 query.awaitTermination()

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it

Answer (score 2):

This RDD aspect is simply NOT supported. RDDs are legacy and Spark Structured Streaming is DF/DS based. Common abstraction whether streaming or batch.

Comment: If it is not supported, how can I read Kafka data as rdds using pyspark streaming, my spark version is 2.4.3 and kafka version is 2.1.0?

Comment: Structured streaming differs.

Comment: @littlely Spark Streaming != Structured Streaming

Comment: is it possible to convert spark Dataframe to streaming dataframe?

Comment: @Innovator-programmer   no it is not

Comment: @thebluephantom coming from Scala Structured Streaming, it's confusing why map functions aren't supported in PySpark? Using UDFs alone in PySpark gets messy when you need to pass an entire row (using Struct) rather than single column.

Answer (score 1):

structured streaming is running on the spark-sql enginer.Conversion of dataframe or dataset to RDD is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

To perform specific actions over your Dataframe fields you can use UDF functions or even you can create your Spark Custom Transformers. But there are some Dataframe operations that are not supported like transforming to RDD.